# Bash avoid filename interpretation

Tags: bash, variables, interpretation

I'm looking at some aliases to quickly save the current directory so it can be opened later.

```
ALIAS cdo='pwd|sed 's/ /\ /g' > ~/.cdo'
AIIAS cdn='cd "$(cat ~/.cdo)"'
```

The sed command obviously deals with spaces.

However, I still have a curious problem that I cannot fix that must involve variable interpretation.

```
jk@bt:~# cd Hello\ World/
jk@bt:~/Hello World# pwd|sed 's/ /\\ /g' > ~/.cdo
jk@bt:~/Hello World# cat ~/.cdo
/home/jk/Hello\ World
jk@bt:~/Hello World# cd ..
jk@bt:~# cd "$(cat ~/.cdo)"
bash: cd: /home/jk/Hello\ World: No such file or directory
```

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 to understand why this behavior is happening: Quoted variable substitution (which is the right thing to use!) doesn't process escapes, nor should it.

Comment: It is much better to solve this problem with [`pushd, popd`](http://cli.learncodethehardway.org/book/cli-crash-coursech8.html) and `dirs` commands available in all flavors of Unix.

Comment: Check out acd_func.sh -- extends bash's CD to keep, display and access history of visited directory names at http://geocities.com/h2428/petar/acd_func.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me as if you're doubling the masking.

One way to handle spaces is to mask them individually with a backslash:

```
 cd here\ I\ go
```

or to mask all of them with double quotes:

```
 cd "here I go"
```

while this would be allowed as well:

```
 cd here" I "go
```

However, mixing them means, that you want literally backslashes:

```
 cd "here\ I\ go"
```

and that's what's happening.

Note that while not very common, tabs and newlines can be included in files as well. Masking them works the same way, but reading them from a file might be different, and multiple blanks are often condensed by the shell to a single one.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape with `\` if the filename isn't between `"` and `"`

Escaping with `cdo` but not using `"` in cdn

```
ALIAS cdo='pwd|sed 's/ /\ /g' > ~/.cdo'
AIIAS cdn='cd $(cat ~/.cdo)'
```

Not escaping and using `""` (I think this is **better**)

```
ALIAS cdo='pwd > ~/.cdo'
AIIAS cdn='cd "$(cat ~/.cdo)"'
```

Comment: The problem, rather, is that he *shouldn't* do manual escaping in contents which aren't going to be parsed. Your second example, then, is correct, but the explanation is misleading.